# How does this function obtain the index value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I went through a code snippet, and this anonymous function is passed the value of index and value as parameters. How is this useful, since we're not manually calling the function at all? (other than via event calls). Further, from where does this index value (which is subsequently used in the function) originate? Who exactly is passing this values, and where do they come from?

```
var hideCode = function houdini()
{
    var numRand = getRandom(4);
    $(".guess_box").each(function(index, value) 
    { 
        if(numRand == index)
        {
            $(this).append("<span id='has_discount'></span>");
            return false;
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: `index` is the nth occurance of `.guess_box` element. This is serializedby jQuery's each after DOM manipulation. If we have 3 elements with class `.guess_box` in the DOM, then each method will loop with index 1, 2, 3...

Comment: @JaromandaX I already know the basics of javascript from head first Javascript, but haven't ever seen an anonymous function being passed a value before. That's why I was confused. As per the answers provided, each() is a jQuery function and not a javascript one, and hence my confusion regarding this is justified.

Comment: @JaromandaX So, if index is a part of an event object, then why aren't we using the dot notation to denote the event object, like eventObj.index?

Comment: oh, you misunderstood ... index is not part of an event object - that's a jQuery function in your post, nothing to do with event handlers ... I used the example of event handlers because it's a common requirement in javascript coding that uses an anonymous function with an argument (i.e. the event object)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for the explanation. I knew that the event object is passed by the DOM to the event handler when an event occurs. Its origin is clear. I was simply confused about where the variables index and value are passed from.

Comment: Here's the best hint I can give you, going forward with your programming career ... jQuery is just a collection of javascript functions, if you think of it as a different language, you'll be forever confused :p Hover over the jquery tag in your question to see that I'm right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so
>   the keyword this refers to the element.

What this means is that it after `$('.guess_box')` is called, the `.each(...)` iterates over the returned array starting from 0 until length-1. This works very similarly to calling a for-loop on the returned array.

The following snippet shows you the results of the iteration using jQuery's `.each()` function compared to a similar iteration using pure Javascript and a for-loop.

```js
var showCode = function houdini() {
  // Prints the results of each iteration so you can see what happens.
  $(".guess_box").each(function(index, value) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
  // In pure JS you would do something like this, which is very similar.
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('guess_box');
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
    console.log(boxes.item(i));
}
$('#tester').click(function() {
  showCode();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="guess_box">test 1</div>
<div class="guess_box">test 2</div>
<div class="guess_box">test 3</div>
<div class="guess_box">test 4</div>
<button id="tester">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

When you write:

```
$(".guess_box").each(function(index, value) 
    { $(".guess_box").each(function(index, value) 
        {
             //do something
        }
```

The index argument taken by the function in each is an iterator which starts with index 0 to length - 1 of the item selected by jquery selector.

Refer - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/